# Ubuntu долго выполняет команду sudo apt-get update если подключение по wi-fi который раздается с Смартфона.?

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu долго выполняет команду sudo apt-get update если подключение по wi-fi который раздается с Смартфона(андроид 4g).? Если подключить на кабельный инет то все происходить быстрее. НО скорость обеих почти одинаковые. Даже иногда wi-fi быстрее чем кабельный

Answer (score 3):

У канала кроме скорости, есть ещё одна очень важная характеристика - rtt (round trip time) - время, за которое пакет пробегает по каналу. В простонародье - длина пинга.

Если нужно скачать один большой файл, то достаточно раздвинуть tcp window и скорость может быть хорошей. Но если нужно скачать много-много мелких файлов ( а собственно это и делает apt-get update), то скорость канала уже не важна, важен rtt.

Почему же так? один запрос не может быть быстрее, чем rtt. А если он 2 секунды (а такое вполне может быть в связке 4G-smart-wifi), то 10 запросов - это 20 секунд минимум. Даже если канал 10 гигабит.

Есть [калькулятор](https://www.switch.ch/network/tools/tcp_throughput/), который позволяет поиграть параметрами. Их вполне можете измерить для своей системы.

Да, запросы идут в параллель, это немного ускоряет, но все же...

А иногда драйвер wifi кривой. И это вносит свои коррективы. А вот ethernet драйвера уже достаточно вылизаны.